# Is it possible to have the Run Configuration GUI auto change to currently open file in PhpStorm or IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

When switching between different open files/tabs in PhpStorm or IntelliJ, I need to manually change the Run Configuration to the one for that specific file each time before clicking the Run/Debug button on the toolbar.

The auto-switching to the current file's Run Config is only possible via the keyboard shortcut, and if Run Config is already available for that file.

Is there a way to have the IDE automatically switch the Run Configuration to the current file via the GUI?
For files which don't have a Run Configuration, is there a way to have it automatically create one when clicking Run/Debug in the toolbar for the first time?

Comment: The answer is "No". The idea of how it works is opposite to what you want: to be able to execute **the same** configuration regardless of what file is currently opened or where the focus is. **#2** is that you can have multiple different configurations for the same file (e.g. run this .php file in CLI or call it via browser; or run PHPUnit tests for the whole or only for specific group etc) -- how to select most correct entry in such case?

Comment: P.S. If currently opened file does not have any Run/Debug Configuration .. then at very least for PHP: the Run and Debug actions from Editor context menu will create and launch one -- for PHP it will be "PHP Script" type of config.

Comment: Maybe there is a plugin that can do what you want... but I'm not aware of any (never looked for one)

Comment: I understand the your reasons why the toolbar doesn't work the way I want, but those same 2 issues exist when selecting Run/Debug from the Editor context menu. So I don't understand why that would have different behavior from the toolbar, despite calling the same action to the IDE. Either way, it seems it is not possible from your explanation so I will accept it for what it is. Thank you!